# Clean the SQL database on continuos CSV import and table dropping

Tags: sql

I am planning to continuously upload a CSV file to SQL database and rename it - so as to replace the older version of the same table. I wonder if it is needed to somehow clean the SQL database of any debris which is left after the following operations:

```
RENAME TABLE `i7048419_wp1`.`macro` TO `i7048419_wp1`.`macroolder`; 
RENAME TABLE `i7048419_wp1`.`TABLE 56` TO `i7048419_wp1`.`macro`; 
DROP TABLE `i7048419_wp1`.`macroolder`
```

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not, but it's interesting question though. Maybe specify which db you work with and this would help to find someone with better domain knowledge.

Comment: this is the only working solution as opposed to using Devart excel plugn to update remote sql database table - which can be slow and buggy